# Como extraigo valores de un data frame a otro data frame utilizando loops y condiciones?

Tags: string, condiciones, bucles, data, caracteres

Quiero crear un data frame extrayendo ciertos valores de otro data frame, para esto lo que hice fue crear `2 matrices de 875 obs` y un `loop` con ciertas condiciones: En fin, lo que quiero es extraer el valor de la variable X2 cuando la variable X1 = "Proyecto:", es decir el valor de la fila.

```
df <- data.frame("AREA"=1:875, "EVALUADOR", "NOMBRE_PROYECTO", "CALIFICACION")

df <- for(i in 1:length(df1)){
  if(df1$X1 == "Proyecto:"){
  df$NOMBRE_PROYECTO <- df1$X2
  } else if(df1$X1 != "Proyecto:"){
    df$NOMBRE_PROYECTO <- 0
  }
}
```

sin embargo tengo este error:

> In if (df1$X1 == "Proyecto:") { :   the condition has length > 1 and
>   only the first element will be used

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias por favor agregar que lenguaje es este?